# Django model instance constants

Tags: python, django

I want to have constants of model instances. Simplified, this looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

constant1 = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(codename="cool")
```

**Of course I can't do that** so simple, because this code will make an attempt to put data in database before any migrations are done, or it will fail because "models aren't loaded" at some point etc etc. But I really want to have constants like this, because I find it convenient for import.

Obvious workaround solution for me - is to make function, like "def constant1():..." or "def get_constant1():..." which will do the same thing, but will never cause any problems at migration stage.

But I want to access my "constant1" like **variable** (something = constant1), not like a function (something = constant1())

Please, tell me, is there a right way to implement constants like this, or I should surrender?

Comment: Why is it necessary to do that in the same file?

Comment: It's not a *constant*, it would be --at the best-- a *well known object*, but it would still be pulled from the database. In essence: populate the database with [initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/) and provide a way to query for well known objects. Your `constant1` would reflect the object as it would be at the time the "constant" was defined, not at the time you would use the object ... have fun debugging that.

Comment: @dhke Sure, I'm ok with that. This is totally expected behavior.